# Marionette: how to use multiple controllers in AppRouter?

Tags: backbone.js, controller, marionette, single-page-application

This would be a repeated question but I'm unable to find any practical answer on how to use multiple controllers in the AppRouter, for example in my code what I'm trying:

```
define([
'marionette', 
 'apps/contents/workpackage/workpackage_controller',
 'apps/contents/overview/overview_controller',

], function(
Marionette, 
WorkpackageController
OverviewController

) {

return Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
initialize: function(options) {
  this.wpcontroller = new WorkpackageController({region: options.region});
  this.ovcontroller = new OverviewController({region: options.region});
},
appRoutes: {
  'wp1': 'wpcontroller#workPackageContents1', //Workpackage Controller
  'overview': 'ovcontroller #overviewcontent' //Overview Controller
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you probably already know, AppRouter doesn't take multiple controllers. But that doesn't mean that you can't modularize your controller objects. What I mean is that you can concatenate several controller objects together. In this example, note that my controllers are plain objects as per the v2.4.4 spec (see [docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.controller.html)). (If you want some Marionette functionality, you can simply use a `Marionette.Object` on one controller and follow the recipe below.)

### Plain JS Objects

So, if controller is defined as:

```
var workpackageController = {
  workPackageContents1: function () {
    // method logic //
  }
}
```

and the other:

```
var overviewController = {
  overviewcontent: function () {
    // method logic //
  }
}
```

then I'd instantiate my AppRouter like this:

```
return Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
  appRoutes: {
    'wp1': 'workPackageContents1', //Workpackage Controller
    'overview': 'overviewcontent' //Overview Controller
  },
  controller: _.extend(workpackageController, overviewController)
});
```

I'm using underscore's `_.extend()` to merge the properties of my controller objects into one object that the `Marionette.AppRouter` can ingest. This implies that the methods in the independent controllers objects must have unique names or there will be name collisions. That is, you lose the namespacing of the formerly independent objects.

This may or may not work for you considering that you're still using one controller object. However, it does allow you to declutter your controller object.

### With Marionette.Object

If you decide to use a Marionette.Object, just change the definition of the first object in `_.extend()` to:

```
var WorkpackageController = Marionette.Object.extend({
  workPackageContents1: function () {
    // method logic //
  }
})
```

and your `_.extend()` will now look like:

```
_.extend(new WorkpackageController, overviewController);
```

where `overviewController` is still a plain object that you're using to simply add more methods to WorkpackageController.

Comment: make sense but now the thing is whenever I'm trying to initialize content router in app.js like: `new ContentsRouter();` I'm getting error:
 **Uncaught TypeError: ContentsRouter is not a function**

I'm using Marionette.Object as controller for both overview and workpackage, probably I'm doing something wrong, appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, like I mention in the last part of the Answer, you only want to use one `Marionette.Object` controller, because otherwise on `_.extend()` you'll have collisions, and anyway, its not at all necessary. `Marionette.Object` will work on the inheriting object (the second argument to `_.extend`) just as well. Also make sure that there are not other errors in your `AppRouter`.

Comment: I'm accpeting @seebiscuit answer, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create two (or more router instances each one with its own controller):

```
var WorkpackageRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {
    'wp1': 'workPackageContents1'
 },

 controller: new WorkpackageController({region: options.region});
});

var OverviewRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {
    'overview': 'overviewcontent'
 },

 controller: new OverviewController({region: options.region});
});

//later
var router1 = new OverviewRouter();
var router2 = new WorkpackageRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: You're not even close to what I'm trying to achieve, I think you're unable to understand what I'm saying, anyway thanks for the contribution but I've accepted another answer.